# Inner join sql

Tags: php, join, inner, sql

Ребята, вообщем есть таблица tasks и tasks_categories_ent. Есть связка с INNER JOIN:

```
INNER JOIN `tasks` ON users.vk_id = tasks.tvk_id INNER JOIN tasks_categories_ent ON tasks.tid = tasks_categories_ent.tce_eid
```

До внесения `INNER JOIN tasks_categories_ent ON tasks.tid = tasks_categories_ent.tce_eid` выводились все материалы. А теперь получается, что выводятся те материалы, id которых забит в таблицу **tasks_categories_ent** поле **tce_eid**. То есть если в tasks_categories_ent 2 записи, то и из tasks выводятся 2 записи. Нужно чтобы выводились все материалы и в случае, если в tasks_categories_ent есть id материала нужного, просто вывести что-то напротив.

Comment: используйте агрегатные функции min или max по tce_eid. с добавлением group by по всем остальным полям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
... LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories_ent ON tasks_categories_ent.tce_eid = tasks.tid
```

Comment: left join вернет записей не меньше чем inner. будет по прежнему две записи.

Comment: @renegator, есть же умные люди. Огромное спасибо!